# Using AWS cognito Identity with openID salesforce in python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, salesforce, boto3, amazon-cognito

I am doing a POC for an application that will use SSO from Salesforce using OpenID and pass the id_token to cognito user identity to get temporary credentials for s3. I have set up all the roles and services and app on AWS/Salesforce. I am able to access s3 when I enable unauthorized access for my identity. But whenever I try to pass the id_token for authenticated access it throws me this error:

> botocore.errorfactory.NotAuthorizedException: An error occurred
>   (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the GetId operation: Invalid
>   login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName

I am following the tutorial here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/building-an-app-using-amazon-cognito-and-an-openid-connect-identity-provider/

I am using python Boto3. This is my current code:

```
import boto3

id_token='aaaaaa.bbbbbbbb.cccccccc' #Got from the url salesforce sends after successful authentication
client = boto3.client('cognito-identity', 'us-east-2')
resp = client.get_id(AccountId='123456789123', IdentityPoolId='us-east-2:xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzz-hhhhh-jj888hhhh',
                     Logins={
                         'provider_url': id_token
                     }
                     )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the provider_url as the error suggested. I was simply putting login.salesforce.com when instead i had to change it to what the id_token was returning as their issuer id. I had to change it in the AWS access providers in IAM as well as in code.